# CrystalReportViewer for VS 2010 Exporting to Excel (Data-Only) has Misaligned Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I upgraded a site to ASP.NET 3.5 using the Crystal Report Viewer for Visual Studio 2010 (13.0.3) control library (AJAX control.) Almost everything works except that the built-in Export button is now misaligning column data when exporting to "Excel (97-2003) Data-Only."

Looking into this I found several comments suggesting fixing the report's layout but I know this isn't the problem because these exact same reports exported fine with the older Crystal control (11.0.3300.)

How can I fix this? I read that by changing settings to maintain relative object position, maintain column alignment, and simplify page headers it will export correctly but I don't see a way to set these values for the default export button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately we ended up having report writers go through and resave every report using the latest report writer version. They didn't need to manually change anything in the reports, just save them again in the newest version.

Would have preferred a programmatic solution but this did solve it.